# How does mask affect stencil value according to stencil op?

Tags: opengl, stencil-buffer

The documentation in OpenGL reference pdf (both OpenGL 3.3 and 4.5 specs) is not much clear about what happens to the stored stencil value when a mask is applied.

In example If I have the following mask:

```
glStencilMask( 0x06);
```

and stored in the stencil buffer there is already this value:

```
0x06
```

If the stencil operation is `GL_INCR_WRAP`

what should happens when StencilOp is correctly invoked on that pixel?

Basically I have the mask:

```
00000110
```

and the value

```
00000110
```

and I try to increment it, is it wrapped?

```
00000010
```

or is it just zeroed? `(00000110 + 1) & mask`

```
00000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 17.4.2 "Fine Control of Buffer Updates" of the [OpenGL 4.5 core profile specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf) states:

> The commands
>   `void StencilMask( uint mask );`
>   `void StencilMaskSeparate( enum face, uint mask );`
>   control the writing of particular bits into the stencil planes.
>   The least significant s bits of `mask`, where s is the number of bits in the stencil buffer, specify an integer mask. Where a 1 appears in this mask, the corresponding bit in the stencil buffer is written; where a 0 appears, the bit is not written.

The `glStencilMask()` parameter controls which bit planes are *written* to the stencil buffer. It does not control what is read, or how `glStencilOp` operates.

Section 17.3.5 "Stencil Test" states (my emphasis):

> For purposes of increment and decrement, the stencil bits are considered as an
>   unsigned integer. Incrementing or decrementing with saturation clamps the stencil
>   value at 0 and the maximum representable value. Incrementing or decrementing without saturation will **wrap such that incrementing the maximum representable value results in 0**, and decrementing 0 results in the maximum representable value.

The stencil mask itself is not relevant in that stage of the pipeline. It is only applied when the fragment is finally written to the framebuffer, like all `gl*Mask()` functions.

So having the value `0110` in the buffer and applying `GL_INCR_WRAP` leads to `0111` and when this is written the buffer, the mask is applied, so you basically end up with `0110` again (and not 0).

Also note that there is also a `mask` parameter in `glStencilFunc()` defining a bit mask to be applied before the stencil test. Quoting section 17.3.5 again: (my emphasis):

> `StencilFunc` and `StencilFuncSeparate` take three arguments that control
>   whether the stencil test passes or fails. `ref` is an integer reference value that is used in the unsigned stencil comparison. Stencil comparison operations and queries of `ref` clamp its value to the range [0; 2^s - 1], where s is the number of bits in the stencil buffer attached to the draw framebuffer. **The s least significant bits of `mask`
>   are bitwise ANDed with both the reference and the stored stencil value, and the resulting masked values are those that participate in the comparison controlled by `func`.**

So if you want to wrap around a at some value 2^n-1, you can simply ignore the additional bits in the stencil buffer and just test these bits in the stencil test.

Comment: Thanks, that's a perfect answer:) so bascially `glStencilMask` just mask a value before it is wrote to buffer, while `glStencilFunc`'s mask is used only during stencil test in a way like `( ref & mask ) operator ( stencil & mask )`